# Why Flutter App open in Chrome instead on Emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications, android-emulator

Hi just clone one Application from github and run but app open in Chrome but i wanted it to open in Emulator .

Comment: You need to select the preferred device before running the app, chances are that the selected category is `Chrome (Web)`, change by selecting any Android Emulator. But the app also needs to have support for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

You must open your emulator before run app on vscode

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

- If you' re a VS Code user:

- open your project
- press F5
- select your Emulator if you had one, if you didn't had one or your emulator doesn't show up, check online how to fix it . You can check this link: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pj99_CarIA4**

- If you're a Android Studio user: It will automatically run the emulator for you